# Why is my server returning error 500 while trying to set a cookie?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express

I have an express v4 server with a route called admin. When the user post a password to the admin route, I want to respond by setting a cookie on the user's browser and sending a small json. For some reason, the server keeps returning error 500 when trying to respond. I'm assuming that this is something to do with the cookie as I can do "res.send()" without any problem. I'm new to express/nodejs so any help is appreciated.

admin.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');


/* POST HANDLER */
router.post('/', function(req, res) {

    var on = {'admin' : "on"};
    res.cookie(cookie , 'cookie_on').send(on);


});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var admin = require('./routes/admin');
var blogposts = require('./routes/blogposts');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/admin', admin);
app.use('/blogposts', blogposts);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: check the server logs for details on the error 500.

Comment: @devlincarnate It just says "POST /admin 500 582.134ms -1260". Is there a way to get more info(again, I'm new to express)?

Comment: after each `res.status(err.status || 500);` just add `console.log(err)` and investigate the problem. Express can't say you anything, cause it's your code generating error

Comment: Says: "cookie is not defined"... Got it, cookie should have been 'cookie'

Answer (score 0):

Dumb mistake: Cookie should have been 'cookie'...